# Use jQUERY on repeating Form, which increase ID subsequently

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, forms

I have a Front End Form, which edits Posts in a WordPress Loop.

This means, on a certain page, I Loop through a Custom Post Type, and for each returned Post, I render a Form which edits the Post in the Loop, instead of the Post itself.

This creates a Form ID like this, for each form:

- first post in loop: cred_form_1096_1
- second post in loop:cred_form_1096_2
- third form in loop: cred_form_1096_3

etc.

The number of Forms is dynamic, as it is a Loop returning certain content based on certain parameters.
There might be only 3 forms in the loop, on another day, there might be 5, because some new posts where published.

I use this jQuery to send the form via AJAX, when "Submit" is clicked:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
jQuery('#cred_form_1096_1').ajaxForm(function() { 
    alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
}); 
});
```

of course the above only works on first Form in Loop, and for the second Form in Loop, and third, etc, I would need to manually adapt the ID each time!
(#cred_form_1096_2, #cred_form_1096_3 etc)

Is there a way to (example) use some thing similar as:
   `#cred_form_1096_$` ?

Means, the last number in the Form ID should adapt according to the form in Loop.

Or even better, it should just "use" any number in the last position 
like: cred_form_1096_any

If it's the first form in the loop, use cred_form_1096_1, if it's the second, use cred_form_1096_2, etc.

Not sure at all this can be done?

Any inputs are welcome.

UPDATE::

The first answer here worked like charm, I am sure all other do too!

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
jQuery("[id^=cred_form_1096]").ajaxForm(function() { 
    alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
}); 
});
```

I use now `("[id^=PART_OF_ID]")`

Comment: you can add a CSS class and loop throughout this class

Comment: OK, I am not sure I understand, unfortunately! Sorry, I am a very beginner in JS/AJAX etc. How should I proceed? add a class to my Edit form (lets say to the submit button) and then use this class as #id in jQuery?

Comment: with `$(".cssClass")` you can loop on elements with this class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hm,

you should consider using attribute selector to achieve this.

You can target f.e. form with id which starts with PART_OF_ID:

```
$("[id^=PART_OF_ID]").ajaxForm(function () { ...
```

You can also seek for all elements which contain (*=) or end up with ($=) known part of ID/class/type f.e.

Comment: in five minutes I will accept your answer, and I updated my question with the solution (built on your suggestion) THANKS

Comment: you're welcome =) These are really useful selectors when are dealing with generated markup.

Comment: out of curiosity, could you put a example of the 2 possibilities you mentioned ? (seek for all elements which contain (*=) or end up with ($=) known part of ID/class/type f.e.) I am not sure how to implement the code for those, and am sure they will come in handy in future!!

Comment: I see, all what basically changes is id^, id$ and id*. Perfect, thank you

Comment: OK, now I am probably over-using your help, but perhaps you have ideas here: [I can post it only in 90 minutes form now :(] Will update here ASAP. Its about "how to display the post after it has been submitted without reloading the page (AJAX)"

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31418723/display-post-with-ajax-after-submitting-post-with-ajax
can't edit above anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

Say that i is an increment value. You could simply do:

```
$('#cred_form_1096_'+i)
```

Comment: for some weird reason this doesn't work on my end, although it would make a (logical) sense!

Comment: do you mean, I must first declare what "i" is, and then use it your above way? so, as example, i=1 ?

Comment: Yes. The example above assumes that i already has a value that increments for each time you loop through the code. This can simply be achieved by defining i before the loop starts, and then using i++ inside the loop.